# Log-log regression model vs. that in levels

Tags: regression

Assume that we have a log-log regression model of the form:
$$
\log\left(Y\right)=\alpha+\beta\log\left(X\right)+u
$$
Here, the elasticity is defined as
$$
\epsilon=\frac{\text{d}\log Y}{\text{d}\log X}
$$
Here, the interpretation of the elasticity is essentially the extent
to which $Y$ changes in percentage terms (upto a first order approximation)
to a response to an increase in $X$ by 1 percent. My question is,
how is this different from the model:
$$
Y=\gamma X+v
$$
where $\gamma$ measures the impact on $Y$ to a unit-change in $X.$
The quesion then is, how is $\gamma$ related to $\beta?$ We know
that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ will definitely be of the same sign, but
different magnitudes. Intuitively, when is the log-log model more
useful/informative? How can one intuitively think about the percentage
interpretation as opposed to the level interpretation in the second
model?

Comment: I have never seen $\epsilon$ in a regression mean anything but "error".  How does it equal "elasticity"?

Comment: Sorry I used the same symbol by mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already stated how they vary; if you want the math behind the comparison, maybe someone else can give it.  Of course, in any particular regression, we can run both and see the difference.

As to when one is more useful than the other, I would say that the log model is more useful when we think of the variables in multiplicative rather than additive terms. A common example is variables related to money, such as prices or salaries. A \$5,000 change in the price of a car is a lot "more" than a \$5,000 change in the price of a house.

So, let's say Y is total wealth of a person and X is annual income. Then the log version says "a 10% increase in income is associated with a XX % increase in wealth" while a level version says "a \$10,000 increase in income is associated with a XX dollar increase in wealth".   To me, the first seems more useful (of course, both these models are too simple; this is just the example that popped into my head).

(I'm leaving aside any questions of taking logs in order to improve model fit or meet the assumptions of the model, as those don't seem to be what you are asking about).

Comment: Just to clarify. When you say log model is more useful when we think of variables in multiplicative terms, do you imply that this model is useful when both variables move in a constant proportion to each other (i.e. a factor)?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.